# On Windows 8.1 "javac -version" works but Cordova doesn't recognize it

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to set up Cordova. When I run `cordova build android` I receive the following error:

```
(node:6816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
```

However I can run `javac -version` just fine.

```
C:\>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_161
```

I've tried to set `JAVA_HOME` in various ways: pointing to the root; pointing to the `bin` folder; set it as a User variable and also a System one; add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `Path` (both for User and System) and so on.

I've checked several articles about this issue, and they say that if I'm able to use `javac -version` then that's supposed to indicate that my environmental variables are set correctly. Even if that's the case, Cordova still doesn't seem to recognize it.

## Update

Following Stephen C's instructions, I've reset my variables, yet my error still persists. As you can see in the image I can call `javac` just fine, and both `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` seem to be set in the right way. (Note that actually it is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and not `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin` in the `Path`.)

[image]

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid.  It should not point at the "bin" directory for the JDK.  (The "test" of running `javac -version` does not validate JAVA_HOME, because the `javac` command does not use JAVA_HOME.  The articles you found are misleading ... or you misread them.)

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but this doesn't help much. I've tried every possible way I could set these variables, with and without bin, too.

Comment: Maybe is a space char problem (Windows historically doesn't handle spaces well). Try to replace C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 to %ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_161

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but still the same. I've tried it with mixed case like you suggested, but also with all capitals. Everything works fine, but Cordova fails to recognize it for some reason.

Comment: You said `%JAVA_HOME\bin%`.  Do you actually mean `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` ?

Comment: @StephenC Sorry for the error. I meant to say `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing JAVA_HOME, PATH and CLASSPATH

- The JAVA_HOME variable should be set to the name of a single directory.  Not multiple directories with separators.  The JAVA_HOME directory is the top directory of your JDK or JRE installation.  Not the "bin" directory.
- The PATH and CLASSPATH variables consist of a list of paths.  For PATH the paths are pathnames for directories.  For CLASSPATH the paths are pathnames for directories or JAR / ZIP files (or a particular kind of wildcard).
- The PATH is where the shell searches for commands if you use a command name that is a simple name; e.g. `java` or `javac`.
  `
- The CLASSPATH is one of the ways that you can tell Java tools to look cor compiled classes to load, compile against, etcetera.

Your error message says this:

> Your JAVA_HOME is invalid:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
```

This is wrong for two reasons:

1. JAVA_HOME should not be a path
2. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin is not a Java home.  The Java home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 .... probably.

The other thing you may have gotten wrong is that changes to environment variables do not necessarily propagate.  For example, if you start a shell and then change an environment variable via the Windows GUI, the change may not propagate to the shell.  You may need to exit the shell and restart it to pick up the new value.

If you are unsure, you can run (for example) `echo %PATH%` to see the current value of `PATH` in the current shell or script.

**UPDATE**

According to http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html, you need to:

- install Android Studio
- set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to the location of your Android SDK installation.

It is also recommended that you add the Android SDK's tools, tools/bin, and platform-tools directories to your `PATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and sorry if my example is not clear. I've tried exactly what you've told be before, but that didn't work either. But for the sake of it, I've just tried what you've told me. Set everything back how it was (every variable to it's original state), then set up a `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`. However now I cannot even run `javac -version` anymore. If you type into Google "JAVA_HOME is invalid" then you'll pretty much see all the Stack Overflow issues and other articles I've went through to get it right, and so far without any resolution.

Comment: *"However now I cannot even run javac -version anymore."*  That is because PATH is now incorrect.   What did you set PATH to??

Comment: *"... you'll pretty much see all the Stack Overflow issues and other articles I've went through to get it right"* - please see my "And ... unfortunately ..." aside.   There are numerous cut-and-paste "solutions" in StackOveflow that don't work.  As I said, understand 1) how environment variables work, and 2) what these specific 3 variables do, and you will see what your problem is.

Comment: From what you wrote I've understood the following. `JAVA_HOME` should be, well, Java's home. But in addition to that, I have to leave the "path" to the `bin` folder in the `Path`, so when I'm executing a command, the system knows where to look for it. Now I have: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161` and `Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` (note, there are many more in my `Path`, but these two are Java related, and I've set up the second one by hand). However: the problem still persist. At least when I type `javac -version` I get what I want.

Comment: You might want to run `dir c:\ /x` and use the short name of the program files directory, should be progra~1 or similar

Answer (score 0):

Remove **java.dll** from C:\Windows\System32 (if any).

I'm not sure but It may work correctly.

Comment: There's no java.dll in the System32 folder (at least for me).